# How to interpret $(V^*)^*$, the dual space of the dual space?

Tags: linear-algebra, dual-spaces

Suppose $V$ is a real vector space.

Then $V^*$, its dual space, is the vector space of linear maps $V\to \mathbb R$

How then do I interpret $(V^*)^*$, the dual space of the dual space?

Comment: Yes, it is the dual space of the dual space. Why is that a problem?

Comment: It's the space of linear maps $V^* \to \mathbb R$.

Comment: @nik: Thanks, nik, So they are linear maps of linear maps? I just find it a bit difficult to get my head around...

Comment: well, the dual space itself is a linear space, so that's basically the same thing as $V*$, just for a different V

Comment: @DrStrangelove They are linear maps having a linear map as an input and giving a real number as an output. It is quite difficult to get ones head around at first. It was the same for me. You'll get used to it.

Comment: Luckily, if $V$ is finite dimensional, $(V^*)^*$ is naturally isomorphic to $V$; you can think of $v\in V$ as a map $V^*\to\mathbb{R}$ by $v:f\mapsto f(v)$, and it turns out all linear maps $V^*\to\mathbb{R}$ are of this form.

Comment: [Related explanation of double dual spaces](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2097954/81360)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The space of linear maps $\ell : V \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is itself a vector space, with pointwise addition and scalar multiplication of functions.  Thus, $(V^*)^*$ is the dual of this vector space.

There is a canonical linear transformation $\xi : V \rightarrow (V^*)^*$ defined by $\xi(v) = \xi_v$, where $\xi_v : V^* \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is the linear map given by $\xi_v(\ell) = \ell(v)$.  The map $\xi$ is injective, so when $V$ is a *finite dimensional* vector space, the map $\xi$ is a (canonical) isomorphism $V \cong (V^*)^*$.  However, $\xi$ is not necessarily an isomorphism if $V$ is infinite dimensional.