# How to understand confusing constructions like $f:M\to \Bbb R^{C^{\infty}(M,\Bbb R)}$?

Tags: differential-geometry, elementary-set-theory, differential-topology

I have struggle with understanding details of the following construction: Let $M$ be a smooth manifold. consider $F:=C^{\infty}(M,\Bbb R)$, Now consider the following $f:M\to \Bbb R^F$!!!

What is going on? First we collect all real value and smooth maps to a set $F$, then we consider $\Bbb R^F$ that is $\{h|h:F\to \Bbb R\}$ then we consider $f:M\to \Bbb R^F$. What is happening here? What are these trying to explain?

Comment: Think of vector fields: they associate to every point a derivation, i.e. a linear functional on $C^\infty(M,\mathbb{R})$, giving an example of $f:M\to \mathbb{R}^F$

Comment: So why in such a complicated way? $f:M\to TM$ isn't more intuitive? what is the advantage of the above construction?

Comment: That depends on what is the aim of the construction is: if you provide more context, I may be able to tell you more

Comment: This is from page 10 of Milnor's char. classes. There he want to show that $M$ is a submanifold of $\Bbb R^F$. and I wonder why $\Bbb R^F$?

Comment: @C.F.G The point is that we want a real vector space $V$ into which we can necessarily embed $M$. $\Bbb R^F$ is constructed in a complicated way, but the important takeaway in the context is that $\Bbb R^F$ is a vector space and $i:M \to \Bbb R^F$ is a diffeomorphism with its image. So, the question of existence is settled for any manifold $M$.

Comment: @C.F.G If you are familiar with the isomorphism between a vector space and its double dual (or more generally, the *embedding* of a vector space in its double dual), then you might find it helpful to think of this embedding as being the natural generalization of this idea to the context of manifolds.

Comment: @C.F.G If you have some exposure to category theory, you might also like to think of this as the of representation of an object given by the [Yoneda lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoneda_lemma)

Comment: @C.F.G If the embedding of a vector space into its double dual is something you find unintuitive, you might find my [answer here on the topic](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2097954/81360) to be helpful. I believe that if you understand the embedding for vector spaces, then the embedding for manifolds will feel "natural".

Comment: @BenGrossmann: After glancing to "Yoneda lemma" it seems that this construction is recurrent in mathematics, and I should take it easy although it is cumbersome a bit.

Comment: But from smooth manifold point of view it is hard to see for me.

Comment: @C.F.G In two sentences, the punchline (for manifolds and vector spaces) is this: in many situations, it is convenient to identify a point in $x$ with the associated "evaluation" $\alpha_x$, which is defined by $\alpha_x(f) = f(x)$. This identification will always be injective and "structure preserving" (i.e. linear or differentiable)