# Example where $(V^*)^*\neq V$?

Tags: functional-analysis, dual-spaces

Let $V$ be a vector space. [This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/417323/477746) gives a nice explanation of why the "dual dual space" of $V$, i.e., $(V^*)^*$, is isomorphic to $V$ if $\dim V<\infty.$

1. Can someone give an example where $\dim V=\infty$ and $(V^*)^*\ncong V$? I'm having a hard time imagining this.
2. Additionally, must $V$ always be at least isomorphic to a *subspace* of $(V^*)^*$? It seems that the answer must be yes, since we can always define $\xi_{v∈ V}:V^*\to\mathbb R, \omega\mapsto\xi_v(\omega):=\omega(v).$

Comment: This [math overflow post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/49351/does-the-fact-that-this-vector-space-is-not-isomorphic-to-its-double-dual-requir) should answer your questions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you use the tag "functional analysis", I'll assume that you talk about continuous duals.

Let $V=c_0$, that is the space of complex sequences that converge to zero. It is well-known (and fairly easy) to show that $V^*=\ell^1(\mathbb N)$, and $V^{**}=\ell^\infty(\mathbb N)$.

In both cases the duality is $$\langle x,y\rangle=\sum_nx_ny_n.$$

The space $c_0$ is norm-separable, while $\ell^\infty(\mathbb N)$ isn't.

As for your second question, yes, you always have a canonical injection $V\to V^{**}$.

---

For completion's sake, the answer is similar if we consider the purely algebraic dual. Take $V=\mathbb R[x]$, the space of real polynomials. It has a countable basis, namely $\{x^n\}_{n\in\mathbb N\cup\{0\}}$. For each $t\in\mathbb R$ consider $\phi_t:\mathbb R[x]\to\mathbb R$ given by $\phi_t(p)=p(t)$. The uncountable set $\{\phi_t\}$ is linearly independent, so $\dim V^*>\dim V$. Then $\dim V^{**}\geq\dim V^*>\dim V$ and they cannot be isomorphic (the fact that the dimension of the dual is at least that of the space follows from considering dual basis).

Comment: I'm a little bit confused. What does the $\mathbb{N}$ mean in $\ell^1(\mathbb{N})$? The range of the sequences is a subspace of $\mathbb{N}$?

Comment: @Botond You can generally consider $l^1(X)$ for any set X - this is the space of real or complex valued functions on $X$ which are integrable with respect to counting measure.

Comment: I see, thank you @Slup. And how do you identify the duals with those spaces? I can't really imagine the elements of a dual without an inner product (well, maybe the zero functional is an exception).

Comment: There is a hole industry in functional analysis that describes topological duals of various typical spaces.  In the case above you can try to do it yourself (it is an interesting and nontrivial exercise) or look it up in a textbook.

Comment: @Slup I have a functional analysis course currently, but I don't see how can we identify $(c_0)^*$ with $\ell^1$. On a Hilbert space $H$, it's clear that we can identify $H^*$ with $H$ because of the Riesz representation theorem, but it does not work here.

Comment: Ok. Pick $(a_n)\in l^1$. Then it induces a functional $c_0\ni (b_n)\mapsto \sum_{n}a_nb_n\in \mathbb{R}$. You have to check that is bounded functional and that all functionals on $c_0$ are of this form. There are also other things to verify...

Comment: Thank you again, @Slup

Comment: @Slup this was one of the topics at today's class :)

Answer (score 4):

One can give a simple argument based on cardinality counting for the algebraic case.

Suppose that $V$ is a vector space of dimension $\mathrm{card}(I)$. Then $V$ is isomorphic to a direct sum $k^{\oplus{I}}$ of $I$-copies of $k$. Next

$$\left(k^{\oplus I}\right)^* = \mathrm{Hom}_k(k^{\oplus I},k) \cong k^{\prod I}$$

where the right hand side is the product of $I$ copies of $k$ (considered as a vector space over $k$). Suppose now that

$$\mathrm{card}(k) < \mathrm{card}(I)$$

Then

$$\mathrm{card}\left(k^{\prod I}\right) \geq  \mathrm{card}\left(2^I\right) > \mathrm{card}(I) = \mathrm{card}\left(k^{\oplus I}\right)$$

This implies that under the assumption $\mathrm{card}(I) > \mathrm{card}(k)$ we have

$$\mathrm{card}(V^*) > \mathrm{card}(V)$$

In particular $\mathrm{dim}(V^*) > \mathrm{dim}(V) = \mathrm{card}(I)$. Now you can use exactly the same argument to show that

$$\mathrm{card}(V^{**}) > \mathrm{card}(V^*)$$

So in general $V$ and $V^{**}$ do not have the same cardinality.

Answer (score 3):

For the first question. For every vector space $V$ it is true that 
$$
\dim(V)\leq \dim(V^*)
$$
with equality if and only if $V$ is finite dimensional (see Theorem 3.12 in *Advanced Linear Algebra* by Steven Roman). Thus, if $V$ is infinite dimensional, then $V\not\cong V^{**}$, so every infinite dimensional vector space serves you as an example.

For question 2: Yes.